# Store GET-Var in Prestashop while customer registers

Tags: prestashop-1.7

What is the easiest way to store a get-var into Prestashop `ps_address` table when a new customer registers in his user record?

Comment: it's ok for you ?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm totally new to Prestashop and well also my lack of OOP didn't help. I tried: adding my field `affiliateid` to `ps_address` add my field in definition array in classes/address.php, declared a var with the same name and altered the add-method (added `$this->affiliateid = $_GET['pid']`) but doesn't work this way :-(

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the native address class, so to do something like

```
$address = new Address();
$address->firstname = Tools::getValue('firstname');
$address->lastname = Tools::getValue('lastname');
$address->address1= Tools::getValue('address1');
...
$address->save();
```

You can have the list of available fields in the class, otherwise here they are:

```
public static $definition = array(
    'table' => 'address',
    'primary' => 'id_address',
    'fields' => array(
        'id_customer' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_manufacturer' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_supplier' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_warehouse' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId', 'copy_post' => false),
        'id_country' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'required' => true),
        'id_state' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isNullOrUnsignedId'),
        'alias' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
        'company' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'size' => 255),
        'lastname' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 255),
        'firstname' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 255),
        'vat_number' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName'),
        'address1' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isAddress', 'required' => true, 'size' => 128),
        'address2' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isAddress', 'size' => 128),
        'postcode' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isPostCode', 'size' => 12),
        'city' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isCityName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 64),
        'other' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isMessage', 'size' => 300),
        'phone' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isPhoneNumber', 'size' => 32),
        'phone_mobile' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isPhoneNumber', 'size' => 32),
        'dni' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isDniLite', 'size' => 16),
        'deleted' => array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool', 'copy_post' => false),
        'date_add' => array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate', 'copy_post' => false),
        'date_upd' => array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'validate' => 'isDate', 'copy_post' => false),
    ),
);
```